# How to deploy React app and Nodejs backend on the same directory in the subdomain?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, web-deployment, filezilla

I have a React application and I made the backend with Node js also the server from MongoDB. It is a MERN stack. I have a directory structure like:

```
-client  // this is where react app, in build version is in client/build
-middleware
-models
-routes
package.json
server.js
...
```

I want to deploy it like this, in my Filezilla:

```
-test.Server22c
      -backend // this is where all nodejs files
      -static    //these folder and other files are my build files in react app client/build
      -index.html
      ...
```

How can I arrange to work these together in the same folder? I changed the endpoints in my Axios post links in my react redux but it did not work

Comment: You got two options to serve 2 servers on the same domain/subdomain. First one is too **use different port**, for example you could serve your react application on http default port 80 and your node.js server on a random free port like 3000 or 8080. Second one is too **use a reverse proxy** server that redirects requests to one or another server based on the root url like `mydomain.com/react` (redirected to react app) and `mydomain.com/node` (redirected to node.js).

Comment: Is there any example for this? and there will be one backend(node.js) one frontend(react) in the same directory(different folders)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use **2 different ports**, one for your react application and one for your node.js server.

Let's say we'll use :

- HTTP default port **80** for React App (http://example.com)
- Custom port **8080** for your Node.js server (http://example.com:8080)

**React**

To deploy React, you can simply use `serve` and you can find all you need at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/.

You will basically need to execute these commands in your react directory.

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build -l 80
```

> Be sure to not have any apache server running on your machine otherwise the port 80 will be already taken.

**Node.js**

You just need to run your server on the port 8080, I do not really know which framework you're using, so let's say if you were using express, it will looks something like this in your entry point `index.js`.

```
app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 8080...");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it React part is ok but the problem is, How can I deploy Nodejs backend and make it running? now my backend doesn't work, I couldn't reach db

Comment: @OnerT. to run **Node.js** you have to simply do `node index.js`. But this will end as soon as you close your terminal, to keep a Node.js server running, look at `forever`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: if both are running in the same machine, what should be the endpoint to connect to the backend ?
Can we use localhost ?